# X11 Connection Rejected Because of Wrong Authentication

Tags: xorg, ssh

I'm trying to run `gparted` on my Raspberry Pi. After logging in with `ssh -X pi@pi` and trying to run `sudo gparted`, I get the error message...

> X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

When I try `xauth list`, nothing is shown, meaning that the xauth file is missing. What is the easiest way of getting the X11 forwarding to work?

---

Edit: I tried the suggestion from below, but the first step already fails:

> root@raspberrypi:~# xauth list $DISPLAY
>
> xauth:  file /root/.Xauthority does not exist

How do I generate this file?

Comment: Is there actually an X session to forward the remote session to? You're not doing this in putty are you?!

Answer (score 13):

A convenient way is to use the `gksudo` command instead.  (From the debian package "gksu").

Comment: Yeah, this is probably a better, easier solution.

Comment: I tried solutions using xauth and similar stuff but this was the only solution that actually worked for me!

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that the X session for the superuser doesn't know what the cookie is.

After logging into the Pi execute the following:

```
$ xauth list $DISPLAY
```

This prints the cookie, something like this:

```
pi:10 mit-magic-cookie-1 4d22408aga55sad1ccd165723g77923ae
```

Then switch the superuser with `su` and set the cookie:

```
# xauth add pi:10 mit-magic-cookie-1 4d22408aga55sad1ccd165723g77923ae
```

X-forwarding should now work for root.

Comment: Is there an arguement you can pass to sudo?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Not that I know of.

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. See my edit in the original post.

Comment: @zenbomb It appears you ran `xauth list` as root, which of course fails. You want to list the cookies for the user and add them for root.

Comment: xauth merge is so much more convenient than xauth list followed by xauth add.

Answer (score 5):

So I had the same error:

```
xauth: file /root/.Xauthority does not exist
```

when trying to add the cookie to the root account using (example only)

```
xauth add pi:10 mit-magic-cookie-1 4d22408aga55sad1ccd165723g77923ae
```

I solved this problem by creating the missing `/root/.Xauthority` file (logged in as root):

```
touch /root/.Xauthority
```

The command `touch` creates an empty file. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

**1.** ssh mitter@host'

**2. $** sudo su

**3. #** xauth merge /home/mitter/.Xauthority

Configure $DISPLAY variable, if it is not configured.

Comment: what is mitter?

Comment: "mitter" is his particular user name. What user name you want to merge depends on what system you're running, and what user you're logging in as initially. On a Raspberry Pi, the default user name is "pi." On many Ubuntu installations, the default user name is "ubuntu."

Answer (score -1):

i fixed it with a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /home/[my username]/.Xauthority /root/.Xauthority
```

Comment: Bad idea.  That will create a permissions problem for [username] if you use the root account with X.

Answer (score -2):

i just cp'ed the .Xauthority from /home/user to /root

Comment: This is officially frowned upon because it establishes bad habits which get you in trouble on multi-user machines. Works like a treat on single user machines.